# xmlhttprequest: network error 0x800c0019, security certificate required to access this resource is invalid. WINJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ssl-certificate, winjs

Good morning,

I need to access a https web service, try to make a GET using JQUERY, WINjs.xhr, Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient, .ajax ().

I download the certificate .cer and add in the package.appxmanifest.
But when I do the call to service I get the following error:

**xmlhttprequest: Error 0x800c0019 network, security certificate required to access this resource is invalid.**

I've tried everything, and it implosible for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to make a GET request on the main web service domain before others types of request ?

Bevause It worked for me.